# How to Center React Component Horizontally and Vertically Using Inline Styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, inline-styles

I'm trying to center a basic user login in React JS using inline styles, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I'm using React Bootstrap and I have currently managed to partially center the form using flexbox, but it's still appearing at the top of the page. What do I need to do so that it appears right in the middle?

Please see the attached image for the current issue.

```
const LoginPage = () => {

    return (
        <Container >
            <Row
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop:'5px'
                }}
            >
                Enter API Key:
            </Row>
            <Row
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop:'5px'
                }}
            >
                <Form>
                    <Form.Control
                        id='apiKeyString'
                        name='apiKey'
                        size='sm'
                        style={{ width: '250px' }}
                        onChange={(e) => setApiKey(e.target.value)}
                    ></Form.Control>
                </Form>
            </Row>
            <Row
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    marginTop:'5px'
                }}
            >
                <Button type='submit' onClick={submitApiKey} size='sm'>
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should wrap your `Row`s in a div and then set the styles on the div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To center vertically you'll have to set the Container inline style to the following:

```
{
height: '100vh',
display: 'flex',
flexDirection: 'column',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
}
```

This being done you can probably remove all the other styling.